# Long load time on Vimeo using HLS

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm a Vimeo PRO member, and I'm using HLS to stream videos from my Android App, getting the direct links from the Vimeo API. I noticed that it's very slow to load any video this way, much longer than using progressive download with High Def. I have to wait for a long time before the video starts playing (up to 10 seconds with HLS, compared to less than 2 seconds with standard link). Is there any known reason for this? Is on-the-fly .gzip compression of .M3U8 index files enabled on Vimeo?

HLS is supposed to improve user experience by reducing loading times, especially on mobile devices. I need this to work properly.

Thanks.